# Get the same display using an ActionLink inside Html.BeginForm and simple <a> tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 website I have a menu with two types of files: actual pages returned from the controllers and pdf files that you can view in the navigator. Since my menu is created dynamically  (it varies according to Active Directory rights) I have to distinguish which type is which (`Document` or `Page`), and this means that according to the file type you click, it will not result in the same action.

To show you, imagine there is a `List<DocumentModel> documents` and the following to treat the information:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var document in documents)
{
    <li>
        @if (document.type.Equals("Document"))
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayPDF", "Navigation", new { pdfName = document.link }, FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.ActionLink(document.docName, "DisplayPDF", null, new {id="linkStyle", @class = "saveButton", onclick = "return false;" })
            }
        }
        else
        {
         //This link is different then the one above visually
        <a href="~/@document.link" id="linkStyle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>@document.docName</a>
        }
    </li>
</ul>
<!--This script allows to submit the form, and treat the action of DisplayPDF-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.saveButton').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

DocumentModel is as follows:

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    public long idDocument { get; set; }
    public long idCategory { get; set; }
    public string docName { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Finally my DisplayPDF method is the following:

```
    public FileContentResult DisplayPDF(string pdfName)
    {
        var fullPathToFile = @"Your\Path\Here" + pdfName;
        var mimeType = "application/pdf";
        var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPathToFile);
        return new FileContentResult(fileContents, mimeType);
    }
```

Now as you can see in the Razor view I displayed, there are two types of clickable links. One is **only** a controller redirection, whereas the second calls the `DisplayPDF` method and then returns a PDF page. The problem I'm having is that these links are displayed differently, and I don't know how to have the same display for both.

**To synthesize my question** : how to display the same using @Html.ActionLink() and 'a' tag, knowing that currently, the 'a' tag has the proper display?

**Update** I modified some code as to give IDs to `<a>` tag and `@Html.ActionLink`, then I added this css in stylesheet:

```
#linkStyle {
    margin-left: 25px;
    color: antiquewhite;
}
```

But I still have a different display

**UPDATE 2**  I think that the problem of display come from the `BeginForm` method, any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean visually they both look same?

Comment: Well you could surely pass the same style attribute to @Html.ActionLink as for the links you create “manually” ... but the proper solution would rather be to _remove_ the style attribute from the latter, and do the formatting via the stylesheet, as it should be.

Comment: ActionLink generates an `<a href>` type of link. Presumably, the HTML it generates is not the same as the HTML you've written by hand for the other link. There will be some CSS or style attributes different. So you can just make them match - the one you've written by hand, you can make it however you like, so just copy the output of the ActionLink method. Or you can use the htmlAttributes property of the ActionLink declaration to do it the opposite way round. Either way, you should move your inline style properties in your manually produced link into your stylesheet. Then it's _really_ simple

Comment: @TejasVaishnav No they don't, but that's what I want to have

Comment: @ADyson Ok I'll try it out thanks

Comment: @ADyson I've made an edit, tried kinda what you told me but it's not working yet. I feel like because the ActionLink is in a form, it is treated differently

Comment: @CBroe Any ideas from the edits?

Comment: Start by using your browser dev tools, to find out what styles are actually applied.